# Copy values between elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to copy some values between elements but doesn't work.
What's wrong?!
This two rows works well
document.getElementById('ftreturnslbl').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('ftasc1primoritorno').style.display = 'block';

```
function ff_returnasc1primo_action(element, action)
{
    switch (action) {
        case 'click':
            document.getElementById('ftreturnslbl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ftasc1primoritorno').style.display = 'block';        
            document.getElementById('toftasc1primoreturn').value = 
            document.getElementById('fromftasc1primo').value;
            document.getElementById('fromftasc1primoreturn').value = document.getElementById('toftasc1primo').value;
            break;
        default:;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are above elements are `input` type?

Comment: First of all: What are those elements ? Inputs, textareas, divisions, paragraphs, .. ?

Comment: Second: What kind over error do you get? What exactly is not working ?

Comment: All above are type input

Comment: Then it should work. Make sure you have value in source input

Comment: The error is that I can't see copied values on the toftasc1primoreturn and fromftasc1primoreturn fields

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Your posted code should be a [mcve], but at the moment it contains errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works in all common browsers.

I dont know where your error is or how your html looks like, but this is a minimum of the case, which i understood.

```js
function copy(){
 var fromValue = document.getElementById('from').value;
 var returnValue = document.getElementById('return').value;
 document.getElementById('to').value = fromValue;
 document.getElementById('toReturn').value = returnValue;
}

document.getElementById('copyBtn').addEventListener('click',copy);
```

```html
<div>from:</div>
<div>
  <input id="from"><input id="return">
</div>
<div>to:</div>
<div>
  <input id="to"><input id="toReturn">
</div>
<button id="copyBtn">
  Copy
</button>
```